# How to get alt attribute from a specific div image by php dom parser?

Tags: php, parsing, simple-html-dom

How to get alt attribute from a specific div image by php **scraper** ? Just look my following code sample. I can print all img "alt" attribute. But I would like to get the "alt" attribute of a specific div class. How can? Here is my code sample:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(1);
set_time_limit(0);

require 'simple_html_dom.php';
$url = "mylink.com";   
$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
echo $element->alt.'<br>';
?>
```

Comment: http://www.rs.realestate.com.au/cgi-bin/rsearch?a=v&t=res&id=13: _“In accessing or using our websites you agree that you will not: (a) use any automated device, software, process or means to access, retrieve, scrape, or index our websites or any content on our website;”_ … please don’t ask us for help in violating a sites TOS.

Comment: I have edited my question and I think its not violating the rules now. Thanks.

Comment: What you try to do is violating a sites TOS.

Comment: If the site is my own site, then? Just I have put an example site here. Even it can be a file also. I would like to know the parsing process. Thanks.

Comment: You did load your page right before your loop `$html = file_get_html($url);` ? I dont see that in your code!

Comment: Sorry, its a mistake. Look now. Thanks @Enissay

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's say the div's class is `foo`:

```
foreach($html->find('div.foo') as $div) {
  echo $div->alt . '<br>';
}
```